# Relationship between Fourier series & DFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-analysis

Sources like http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/mdft/Relation_DFT_Fourier_Series.html explain the equivalence between FS and DFT.

However, isn't there a flaw? When I integrate over the continuous signal, there is something in **between** the samples (i.e., the sinc interpolation). So the document above shows only that they are equivalent after the continuous signal has been sampled (which is intuitively trivial since the sampled signal contains only Diracs)!

Is it possible to derive a relationship without the signal being sampled?
Suppose for simplicity only the DC component. $\tau$ is the period, $T_s$ the (hypothetical) sampling rate, $N=\tau/T_s$ the number of samples and $x[n]=x(n T_s)$:

$$
\int_0^{\tau} x(t) dt = \int_0^{\tau} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(nT_s) \mathrm{sinc}(t-nT_s) dt =
\dots \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]
$$

Obviously this is not true, due to sinc interpolation, so something is missing on the right side.

Comment: you'll need to assume that the continuous signal has a limited band width, meaning that only a finite number of terms in the Fourier series are nonzero.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean: In the derivation in the link, the signal $x(t)$ is plugged in as $x(t) = \sum_n x(n T_s) \delta(t - n T_s)$ and therefore has **not** finite bandwidth!

Comment: And stated differently: My continuous signal **has** finite bandwidth by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I attempt my own answer. The key is that the continuous-time signal signal is periodic. The definition of above

$$
x(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n T_s) \operatorname{sinc}(t-n T_s)
$$

is *not* a periodic signal but a signal of finite length.
Suppose $N=8$ and the discrete-time signal is $x[0]=1$ and $x[n]=0$ otherwise. The continuous signal (within one period) would look like this:

[image]

As correctly assumed in the question, the area under this curve is not 1. However, compare this to the case when $x(t)$ is periodic:

[image]

Now due to the fact that $x(8 T_s)=1$ too, there is a sinc contribution from this as well. Similarly, there is a contribution from $x(-8 T_s)$, $x(16 T_s)$ etc ... and summing up all contributions gives an area of 1.